# why fgets() not working here?

Tags: pointers, structure, fgets

In the below code scanf() is working for getting the name from the user but fgets() is not working pls someone help me to understand why it's not working

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct university{
    int roll_no;
    char name[16];
}uni;
int main()
{
    uni *ptr[5],soome;char i,j=0;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        ptr[i]=(uni*)calloc(1,20);
        if(ptr[i]==NULL)
        {
            printf("memory allocation failure");
        }
        printf("enter the roll no and name \n");
        printf("ur going to enter at the address%u \n",ptr[i]);
        scanf("%d",&ptr[i]->roll_no);
        //scanf("%s",&ptr[i]->name);
        fgets(&ptr[i]->name,16,stdin);
    }
    while(*(ptr+j))
    {
        printf("%d %s\n",ptr[j]->roll_no,ptr[j]->name);
        j++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Answer (score -1):

First of all, `fgets(char *s, int n, FILE *stream)` takes three argument: a pointer **s** to the beginning of a character array, a count **n**, and an input stream.
In the original application you used the address operator `&` to get the pointer not to the first element of the `name[16]` array, but to something else (to use the address operator, you should have referenced the first char in the array: `name[0]`).

You use a lot of *magic numbers* in your application (e.g. 20 as the size of the `uni` struct). In my sample I'm using sizeof as much as possible.
Given that you use `calloc`, I've used the fact that the first parameter is the number of elements of size equal to the second parameter to preallocate all the five uni struct at once.

Final result is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NUM_ITEMS (5)
#define NAME_LENGTH (16)

typedef struct university{
  int roll_no;
  char name[NAME_LENGTH];
} uni;

int main()
{
  uni *ptr;
  int i;

  ptr = (uni*)calloc(NUM_ITEMS, sizeof(uni));
  if(NULL == ptr) {
    printf("memory allocation failure");
    return -1;
  }

  for(i=0; i<NUM_ITEMS; i++) {
    printf("enter the roll no and name \n");
    printf("You're going to enter at the address: 0x%X \n",(unsigned int)&ptr[i]);
    scanf("%d",&ptr[i].roll_no);
    fgets(ptr[i].name, NAME_LENGTH, stdin);
  }
  for(i=0; i<NUM_ITEMS; i++) {
    printf("%d - %s",ptr[i].roll_no,ptr[i].name);
  }

  free(ptr);
  return 0;
}
```

**Note:** I've added a call to `free(ptr);` to free the memory allocated by `calloc` at the end of the application and a different return code if it's not possible to allocate the memory.